# Redirect page after process complete in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have some process in page. It's downloading a file.

```
<?php

// getting file with CURL
        $ch = curl_init ('http://adress.com/file.csv');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,7500);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
// End Curl Process

// SAVE FILE
    $name = Rand(100000,1000000);
    $fp = fopen('files/'.$name.'.csv','w');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);

// END SAVE PROCESS

// REDIRECT OTHER PAGE
       **header('Location: x.php');**
// END OF PAGE

?>
```

This is allright. But there is a problem. It redirects without complete process. I want to redirect after all processes are done. The file is empty when i redirect with that method.

What must I do? How can i redirect page after all processes are done? php or javascript/jquery.

Comment: how do you know that all processes aren't done? this code should run sequentially

Comment: The problem can't be your redirect - it takes place when the file has already been written. It must be something else. Are you 1000% sure it works if you remove that header line?

Comment: Yes, it works if i don't redirect page.

File is big (40-50 MB). Everything is ok about timeout. Its working if i dont redirect as i say. But i have to redirect for other process (uploading it to somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be fine, and should complete the process before redirecting.

PHP runs in a single thread, so the next statement won't be executed until the previous one completes. This means that your `header()` line won't execute until `fwrite()` has finished writing the file.

In fact, setting a `Location` header doesn't even mean the PHP script stops. You can test this by creating a dummy file and running `unlink()` on it after issuing the `Location` header. The file will still be deleted. All that `Location` does is sends a new location to your browser. Your browser then retrieves the new page before the old one is done running.

Answer (score 3):

I think set a callback when the header is complete is the best solution.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.php.net/');

// here is the hack - Set callback function for headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'read_header');

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Callback function for header
function read_header($ch, $string)
{   
    if (trim($string) == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
        header("location: http://www.php.net"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set sleep(seconds) and check if it's enough for complete process.

Also you can put a simple check:

```
$start_size = 0;
while (1) {
   $new_file_size = filesize($filename);

   if ($start_size != $new_file_size) {
      $start_size = $new_file_size;
      sleep(30)
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all. 

header location function works after all process done. Problem was other part of script. Sorry and thanks again for quick alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't returning the file to the client, you can do the following:

```
  ignore_user_abort();
  header("Content-Length: 0", true, HTTP_RESPONSE_204_NO_CONTENT);
  header("Connection: close", true);
  flush();
```

This will return control back to the client and close the browser connection, but the server-side process will continue to work.

However, I agree with @AgentConundrum that the header() line won't be executed until the other processes are complete.